# What does 'to mark' mean in the UK?

Tags: exams

It is just to evaluate what is right and wrong in a script (i.e., an exam or problem sheet completed by a student), and making notes and comments on that?

Comment: My understanding is that "to mark" in British english is roughly equivalent "to grade" in American english.

Comment: Similarly, if a student is asked what mark they got, the person asking wants to know their grade.

Answer (score 7):

To mark is to evaluate student work based on the rubric established for that work which, itself, will be a combination of University policy, subject policy, and what has been presented in the course administrative documents.

If you are unsure of what is expected of you with marking, it would be wise to discuss this with your head of subjects or course coordinator as you will need to conform to your university's policy on marking and could face issues if your marking deviates from that.

Comment: Yes, they already told me that in some cases it involves giving a grade and in others it does not.

Comment: Your course outline or equivalent should indicate if the assignment in question is summative or formative.

Comment: Yes, they do that too.

Answer (score -1):

Marking is grading but comments are not compulsory as it depends on the policy if the papers will be seen by anyone else after.

I do an excel based exam and there are points for parts (calculations )but no comments necessary.

"correcting" is also a word used...

Comment: But here they also call it marking when I don't have to grade (formative assignments), maybe it is colloquial.

Comment: "Correcting" is how we say it in Spanish.

Comment: @Philosopherofscience correcting (corriger) is also used in French - probably due to etymology...